# Parse the HTML Table

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML table that I need to parse into a CSV file.

```
import urllib2, datetime
olddate = datetime.datetime.strptime('5/01/13', "%m/%d/%y")
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
print("dates,location,name,url")
def genqry(arga,argb,argc,argd):
return arga + "," + argb + "," + argc + "," + argd
part = 1
row = 1
contenturl = "http://www.robotevents.com/robot-competitions/vex-robotics-competition"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'catalog-listing'})
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    try:
        if row != 1:
            cols = tr.findAll('td')
            for td in cols:
                if part == 1:
                    keep = 0
                    dates = td.find(text=True)
                    part = 2
                if part == 2:
                    location = td.find(text=True)
                    part = 2
                if part == 3:
                    name = td.find(text=True)
                    for a in tr.findAll('a', href=True):
                        url = a['href']
                # Compare Dates
                if len(dates) < 6:
                    newdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates, "%m/%d/%y")
                    if newdate > olddate:
                        keep = 1
                    else:
                        keep = 0
                else:
                    newdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[:6], "%m/%d/%y")
                    if newdate > olddate:
                        keep = 1
                    else:
                        keep = 0
                if keep == 1:
                    qry = genqry(dates, location, name, url)
                    print(qry)
                row = row + 1
                part = 1
        else:
            row = row + 1
    except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
        print("Error: " + name)
```

I need to be able to get every VEX Event in that table that is after 5/01/13. So far, this code gives me an error about the dates, that I can't seem to be able to fix. Maybe someone that is better than me can fix this code?  Thanks in advance, Smith.

EDIT #1: The Error That I am Getting Is:

```
Value Error: '\n10/5/13' does not match format '%m/%d/%y'
```

I think that I need to remove newlines at the beginning of the string first.
EDIT #2: Got it to run, without any output, any help?

Comment: You don't have to use Beautiful Soup for that. You could use the python3 HTMLParser: https://github.com/schmijos/html-table-parser-python3/blob/master/html_table_parser/parser.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very poor. Without knowing what the exact error, I would guess the problem is with your `if len(dates) < 6:` block. Consider the following:

```
>>> date = '10/5/13 - 12/14/13'
>>> len(date)
18
>>> date = '11/9/13'
>>> len(date)
7
>>> date[:6]
'11/9/1'
```

One suggestion to make your code more Pythonic: Instead of doing `row = row + 1`, use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Update: Tracing your code, I get the value of `dates` as follows:

```
>>> dates
u'\n10/5/13 - 12/14/13            \xa0\n        '
```